# Loop a function name in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

How would I create a simple loop to create these functions:

```
function hello1(e:Event):void
{
trace("hi");
}

function hello2(e:Event):void
{
trace("hi");
}
```

The function name goes in order until it stops at

```
function hello10(e:Event):void
{
trace("hi");
}
```

I know I can just use one function but I am using this as an example for a larger project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are just like any other object is ActionScript 3, so you can pass them by reference.

Try something like this.

```
var functionList:Array = [];
var func:Function;
var numFunctions:int = 10;
for (var i:int = 0; i < numFunctions; i++) 
{
    func = function(num:Number):void 
    {
        trace(num);
    };
    functionList.push(func);
}

for (var j:int = 0; j < functionList.length; j++) 
{
    func = functionList[j] as Function;
    func(Math.random()* 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to accomplish this.

You could store all function in an array, then call Function pointers.

Or, maybe something like:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class HelloLoop extends Sprite
    {

        public function hello1(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("hi - 1");
        }

        public function hello2(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("hi - 2");
        }

        public function hello3(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("hi - 3");
        }


        public function HelloLoop()
        {
            // not sure what event you are passing
            var event:Event = new Event("unknown");

            for (var i:uint = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                this["hello" + i](event);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: but the whole point of this is that I didn't want to expand it!  I don't want to write 10 functions.  I want a loop

Comment: My example shows 1-3 - I didn't want to balloon the example to 10.  You can use the 3-lines of code for the loop to access (n) functions.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question - it appears you have a set of functions predefined as you state: "I know I can just use one function".  The point of the example is calling functions dynamically.

Comment: I think the example given in the question is an example of what blake305 does NOT want to do. The point is to create and call the functions, all dynamically.